# Potty training tricks

Tags: potty-training

This is probably already been asked. My 3 year old son will tell us that he needs to go potty but only after he has already used it in his pull up. Right now we can't afford to constantly buy pull ups. But don't think he is ready for underwear just yet. What are some tricks that I can use to get him to tell me before he is using it in his pull up. Also he is in daycare.

Answer (score 2):

If your son has a favorite cartoon ,  buy underwear with the characters on them.  Let him know that one he keeps hi pullup clean for 3 days he can start wearing the underwear. As long as the underwear status clean,  he can wear it. But if gets dirty it has to go in the wash and he's stuck  with a "baby pullup" .

There will be inevitable accidents, but the consequences are natural rather than imposed.

Comment: He is getting the hang of pooping in the potty but how to get him to to pee in the potty when he doesn't want his wee wee down.

Comment: Aha ... this calls for my wife's solution.  A few days of old fashioned naturism (and a mop and good deodorizing cleaners) may be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a brief summary of what i did when my son was 2yrs old.

So every time we were together I'd ask him constantly do you want to pee?? Then I'd take him to  go try then we'd joke and make fun about it. Until he got the grip of it.

I never gave up. I was very persistent it took us 3 months then he was set even pooping. This really helped me now he's fine. Kids are different though. This worked.

Instead of potty, I used a portable potty ladder step stool. It lets the child climb to and down from the toilet seat comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

Some parents use a target in the toilet for kids to aim at. Turns aiming into a game.

You could choose an incentive for wearing underwear during the day so you can save the pull ups for night.

There will likely be accidents but ensure you keep positive as negative reactions will set back progress.

One of the things I frequently see in childcare is parents doing all the work for their kids so they arrive with no potty training. Most child care centres require potty trained kids. Our centre does not allow us to change or wipe.

Answer (score 0):

I made my son a chart where we would put stickers into boxes when he successfully peed in the potty, and some number of stickers added up to a small prize (I think it was 7). We discussed beforehand what each prize would be, and I drew a picture of it at the end of the line so he could see his stickers going towards the prize. I think I had a total of 5 prizes for him to earn, and when we were done he was a pro at peeing in the potty. I definitely still had to remind him and *make him go* every couple of hours for a while, but it stopped being a big ordeal. Pooping in the potty was much harder for my son to get the hang of, but this worked well for peeing.

The other thing is that when he had an accident he was responsible for cleaning it up (to the extent that he was able). This meant that potty stuff took longer if he **didn’t** use the potty, which somewhat removed the incentive of “but if I just pee in my underwear that means I don’t have to stop playing.”